# What type of regression should i do?

Tags: r, regression

I wanted to run bivariate regression on 2 variables. The dependent variable is the median income of a graduate and the independent variable is iclevel. iclevel is the college's length of degree offering. [iclevel 1 = Four-year degree ; iclevel 2 = Two-year degree ; iclevel 3 = Less than Two-year degree]. As I was doing the analysis in my project, I started wondering if I could run it as a dummy variable regression. But as iclevel are already in the form of numbers (ie 1 means 4yr degree and so on), they can be considered as if they are already dummy variables.

My hypothesis is that students with a 4yr degree are more likely to earn more than students who graduated with a 2yr or less degree. So my question is should I run bivariate regression on this dataset directly or should I have to do a dummy variable regression here? If I do the dummy variable, then I will take 1 as iclevel 1 (4yr degree) and iclevel 2 (2yr degree) and iclevel 3 (less than 2yr degree) as 0 and then run the bivariate regression. Also, can I do both?

Here is a [link to my database](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1R_IRWrVSWdE-bsTF56UzD56JmOKzCABN?usp=sharing). Here is a graph with a regression line:

[image: This picture shows the relationship between iclevel and income of student].

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1R_IRWrVSWdE-bsTF56UzD56JmOKzCABN?usp=sharing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you compute the conditional median for each of the classes? Without further features you are lacking information to get a better guess for the income.

With more features you could start thinking about regression trees etc.

Answer (score 0):

Other than dummy variables, try investigating a regression model of income (either median, average, mid-mean,...) or log transform thereof, as the dependent variable, versus an intercept and a constant times number of years of education. Further, also try adding the square of years of education to the model.

Logic: Years of education is a proxy for earning potential.

Also, try adjusting your income data as ${$60,000}$ in the southern states is not ${$60,000}$ in New York or California. Look at observations with the same education levels and estimate a correction factor for geographic location.

I hope this helps.